# Azure Function not able to start from visual Studio 2019 .listener unable to start

Tags: azure, azure-functions, listener, azure-storage

When I am trying to run azure function from visual studio 2019.. its giving me below error
The listener for function 'CommAdd' was unable to start.
The listener for function 'CommAdd' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: Calculated MD5 does not match existing property.

Please help.

Comment: are you using the storage emulator?

Comment: There is azurestorageemulator folder in %localappdata% but I never used that.. I just run my function from visual studio..

Answer (score 0):

The storage emulator supports a single account and storage key.

One possible problem is that the storage emulator was installed with a different account than what is being used to access the storage. Another is that the config has been corrupted.

It may be faster to uninstall and reinstall the storage emulator, than finding out exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I have 4 azure functions in that.. this error is coming for only 1 azure function..other 3 are running fine with visual studio

Comment: Then, check the config for that Azure function and compare it with the others